# Bitcoin: How to own a mined block?

Tags: security, bitcoin

How does those who mine in bitcoin end up possessing a mined block?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is a Stack Exchange site specifically for [bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/). Additionally the question doesn't seem to be programming related.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Bitcoin Stack Exchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Why you delete the faculty question ? I already provide an answer for it :(

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as ownership of a block. Once you mine a block, it's everyone's.

If your question is how you get the reward for mining the block and the transaction fees in it, the answer is that the block contains a transaction (called the "coinbase" transaction) that controls how the block reward and fees can later be spent. The person who mines a block gets to choose which transactions go in them, so long as they are legal, and one of them is the mining reward transaction.  Assuming you're not a fool, you've rigged it so that only you can release these funds.